# boot repair update?

Tags: boot

I had not really been aware of this program (Boot Repair) until recently, only now because it seems to be updating almost daily.

Do I need this? Why the constant updates?

Thanks for any info

Comment: How do you install it ? Do you happen to run any `apt-get upgrade` command ? Or is there any automatic upgrade event ?

Comment: boot-repair is not part of the default ubuntu packages so you must have installed it at some point. What version of Ubuntu are you using ? If you have questions about boot repair and / or updates probably best to use the mailing list - https://launchpad.net/boot-repair

Comment: On this computer I use the Software Updater, so Boot Repair shows up practically every time there is software to update.  I don't have any recall of installing it since I can't imagine a need for it.  So I will check the mail list you provided and remove the program.  Thanks for your reply